# cryptsetup ubuntu 20.04 no longer asks for my password

Tags: boot, encryption

I have my hard drive encrypted with ubuntu 20.04, using the installer, When I updated to kernel 5.4.0-47-generic , instead of asking for my password it sits at

```
cryptsetup: waiting for encrypted source device UUID=......
```

If I go under advanced options and boot to kernel 5.4.0-42-generic everything works just fine

Comment: Hello! can you show your `/etc/crypttab`  and do you use a unencrypted boot partition and the rest is full encrypted or do use something else?

Comment: nvme0n1p6_crypt UUID=07c67889-bcc6-4417-a8f8-a420c6c7aee9 none luks,discard

Comment: Ok, that looks fine. How does your layout from your nvme? Is it uncrypted boot and the rest encrypted?

Comment: ```Device              Start        End    Sectors   Size Type
/dev/nvme0n1p1       2048    1085439    1083392   529M Windows recovery environm
/dev/nvme0n1p2    1085440    1288191     202752    99M EFI System
/dev/nvme0n1p3    1288192    1320959      32768    16M Microsoft reserved
/dev/nvme0n1p4    1320960 1084590102 1083269143 516.6G Microsoft basic data
/dev/nvme0n1p5 1084592128 1087520767    2928640   1.4G Linux filesystem
/dev/nvme0n1p6 1087520768 2000408575  912887808 435.3G Linux filesystem
```

Answer (score 1):

I'm experiencing the same problem. This seems to be a bug https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/linux/+bug/1894860.

My solution at the moment is when booting.

1. [open the grub menu](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1242340/how-to-get-to-grub-menu-on-20-04).
2. Select Advanced options for Ubuntu.
3. Select Ubuntu, with Linux 5.4.0-42

Comment: as of 5.11, this doesn't work. groan