# Can't access any websites on wifi. I used to be able to before it auto updated

Tags: networking, wireless, 22.04, iwlwifi, troubleshooting

Edit 2: the advice on the similar question (which didn't look like quite the same problem) didn't help. Still can't get any websites to work.

I'm using Ubuntu 22.04.3 on an old Dell Latitude E3410. `sudo lshw -class network` suggests the on board wifi adaptor is a Centrino Advanced-N 6200 made by Intel. `rfkill list all` doesn't list any soft- or hard-blocked devices. `dmesg` gives "read kernel buffer failed: operation not permitted". I have no idea if that's relevant.

It was all working fine, until it did an auto update the other day (`uname -r` reports 6.2.0-31-generic) and now it can't get on the Internet either to the router (which my wife's macbook connects to fine) or a wifi hotspot from my phone (which I'm using to type this).

I have a wifi icon which seems to suggest there's a connection. I've tried restarting network-manager. I can't connect with a cable as I don't currently have one (I'm on holiday).

Also, I disabled ipv6 (someone suggested this but it didn't help) and aeroplane mode is also off. Wifi is on. Weirdly it seems to have a legit-looking IP address and default gateway, but neither Dropbox, software updates / apt-get nor sites thru a browser are working.

Someone elsewhere suggested using the grub menu to boot to an earlier version of Ubuntu, but there's no grub menu on boot (it's single boot with only one installation of Ubuntu as far as I know).

Is there anything I can try that doesn't require being online? So many of the solutions I've found start with "all you need to do is download X...."

I'm at a very very basic level with Ubuntu, so please explain things slowly

Edit:
`ping -c3 8.8.8.8` gives
64 bytes from 8.8.8.8 icmp_seq=1 ttl=249 time=16.3ms
(then two more lines like that)
3 packets transmitted, 3 received, 0% packet loss, time 2003ms

`ls -al /etc/resolv.conf` gives
lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root 29 Aug 1 2021 /etc/resolve.conf -> ../run/resolvconf/resolv.conf

(retyping this on phone since, obviously, I can't get anything off the laptop)

Comment: You should be able to get a grub menu at boot by pressing left shift or ESC, see https://askubuntu.com/questions/1242340/how-to-get-to-grub-menu-on-20-04

Comment: Thanks - I tried that, it doesn't do anything though.

Comment: Please edit your question to show the result of the terminal command: `ping -c3 8.8.8.8` and also: `ls -al /etc/resolv.conf` Welcome to Ask Ubuntu.

Comment: Thanks, I've put the outputs of those in the question now.

Comment: You can tether the laptop to the phone using a USB cable and report if the internet works this way.

Comment: Please show a new version: `ls -al /etc/resolv.conf` Did you reboot?

Comment: @chili555 output of that is: lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root 32 Sep 4 14:16 /etc/resolv.conf -> /run/systemd/resolve/resolv.conf. I rebooted.

Comment: Just connected it on cat6, and that doesn't work either. At this stage is there any way of just reinstalling the networking services, or would a complete reinstall be quicker? I just use it for typing, so aside from a few docs there isn't anything I'd miss.

Comment: ** IT NOW WORKS ** - found this https://askubuntu.com/questions/1399701/how-to-completely-reconfigure-network-settings-from-scratch-in-20-04 and did `sudo rm /etc/NetworkManager/system-connections/*
sudo service NetworkManager restart `